# Is there a compatible webpack war plugin for webpack v5?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, war, webpack-5

I need to utilize a plugin for webpack that creates a war file for my build outputs. I recently upgraded to webpack 5 and discovered that `webpack-war-plugin` is incompatible with webpack 5 because a line in one of the package files contains `compiler.plugin`, which throws a type error. Is there an updated version of the webpack war plugin that doesn't throw this error or is there another package compatible with webpack 5 I can use to create a war file? I did some research and found out that `webpack-war-plugin` and similar plugins haven't been updated in about 5 or 6 years.

Comment: Any news about it ? Did you find another plugin ?

Comment: No. I wasn't able to find another plugin.